# Travis-CI cannot clone my repository on new container-based infrastructure

Tags: git, travis-ci

I recently upgraded my .travis.yml file to avoid the use of `sudo` and build on Travis' new EC2 infrastructure, but Travis' `git clone` causes the build to fail *before* the `before_install` step is reached, because Travis builder seems to use sudo itself. The following error is thrown:

```
This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which 
does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
```

However, the error occurs when Travis is simply cloning my repo. That is, before the .travis.yml file is even touched (as far as I understand).

[This is the .travis.yml file](https://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleElastix/blob/f14b32da8ea8d4b721c092c5b3357bba9e04b3a3/.travis.yml):

```
sudo: false

language: cpp

compiler:
  - gcc
  - clang

before_install:
  - pwd
  - date -u
  - uname -a
  - $CXX --version

before_script:
  - export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
  - echo $OMP_NUM_THREADS

script:
  - mkdir SimpleElastix-build
  - cd SimpleElastix-build
  - cmake -DWRAP_CSHARP:BOOL=OFF -DWRAP_JAVA:BOOL=OFF -DWRAP_LUA:BOOL=OFF -DWRAP_PYTHON:BOOL=OFF -DWRAP_R:BOOL=OFF -DWRAP_RUBY:BOOL=OFF -DWRAP_TCL=BOOL=OFF ../SimpleElastix/SuperBuild
  - make >/dev/null --jobs=4

after_script:
  - ./SimpleITK-build/bin/SimpleITKUnitTestDriver0 >/dev/null
  - ./SimpleITK-build/bin/SimpleITKUnitTestDriver1 >/dev/null
  - ./SimpleITK-build/bin/SimpleITKUnitTestDriver2 >/dev/null
  - ./SimpleITK-build/bin/SimpleITKUnitTestDriver3 >/dev/null
  - ./SimpleITK-build/bin/SimpleITKUnitTestDriver4 >/dev/null
  - ./SimpleITK-build/bin/SimpleITKUnitTestDriver5 >/dev/null
  - ./SimpleITK-build/bin/SimpleITKUnitTestDriver6 >/dev/null
```

[This is the error message](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/55813858/log.txt) (see link for full log):

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-bcc59c93.prod.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-13
travis_fold:start:system_info
[0K[33;1mBuild system information[0m
Build language: cpp
[34m[1mBuild image provisioning date and time[0m
Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015
[34m[1mOperating System Details[0m
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
[34m[1mLinux Version[0m
3.13.0-29-generic
[34m[1mCookbooks Version[0m
a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e
[34m[1mGCC version[0m
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[Installed databases etc is redacted for brevity, see link for full system information]

travis_fold:end:system_info
[0K
travis_fold:start:git.checkout
[0Ktravis_time:start:010c8fae
[0K$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=SimpleElastixRebase git://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleElastix.git kaspermarstal/SimpleElastix
Cloning into 'kaspermarstal/SimpleElastix'...
remote: Counting objects: 4524, done.[K

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2244/2244), done.[K
Receiving objects:   0% (1/4524)    
Resolving deltas: 100% (2511/2511), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
travis_time:end:010c8fae:start=1427297403999154316,finish=1427297406473918291,duration=2474763975
[0K$ cd kaspermarstal/SimpleElastix
$ git checkout -qf f14b32da8ea8d4b721c092c5b3357bba9e04b3a3
travis_fold:end:git.checkout
[0K
[33;1mThis job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.[0m
[33;1mIf you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml[0m
[33;1mSee http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.[0m
$ export CXX=g++
$ export CC=gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    travis_fold:start:before_install.1
    [0Ktravis_time:start:024aaf70
    [0K$ pwd
```

As is apparent from the log, travis_fold:start:before_install is invoked *after* the error is thrown.

Any insights as to what goes wrong? Is it my setup or worth a bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message

```
This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which 
does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
```

was not an error, just for information. The error was related to misconfiguration of nested folders.